# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; What could ve the problem?

Tags: c#, api, rest, put

While i was doing my put request this error appeared to me:

> "Errore con la tua query: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
> 'UPDADE contratti SET IDSede=3, DataRichiestaServizio=timestamp('2023-01-30 15...' at line 1\r\n
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)\r\n
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)\r\n
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n   at TerrnaovaApi.Controllers.ContrattiController.PutContratti(Int32 id, ContrattiNoId an)
> in C:\Users\a04ma\Downloads\WebApplication1 (2)\WebApplication1\TerranovaApi\Controllers\ContrattiController.cs:line 153"

This is my code:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public JsonResult PutContratti(int id, [FromBody] ContrattiNoId an)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = @"UPDADE contratti SET IDSede=@IDSede, DataRichiestaServizio=@DataRichiestaServizio, DataInizioValidita=@DataInizioValidita, DataFineValidita=@DataFineValidita, DescrizioneOfferta=@DescrizioneOfferta, Utility=@Utility, StatoContratto=@StatoContratto, TipoPagamento=@TipoPagamento, PotenzaImp=@PotenzaImp, PotDisp=@PotDisp, EnergiaAnno=@EnergiaAnno, GasAnno=@GasAnno, UsoCotturaCibi=@UsoCotturaCibi, ProduzioneAcquaCaldaSanitaria=@ProduzioneAcquaCaldaSanitaria, RiscaldamentoIndividuale=@RiscaldamentoIndividuale, UsoCommerciale=@UsoCommerciale WHERE IDRigaContratto=@id";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                mycon.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
                {
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDSede", an.IDSede);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataRichiestaServizio", an.DataRichiestaServizio);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataInizioValidita", an.DataInizioValidita);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataFineValidita", an.DataFineValidita);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescrizioneOfferta", an.DescrizioneOfferta);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Utility", an.Utility);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatoContratto", an.StatoContratto);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoPagamento", an.TipoPagamento);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PotenzaImp", an.PotenzaImp);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PotDisp", an.PotDisp);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnergiaAnno", an.EnergiaAnno);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GasAnno", an.GasAnno);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsoCotturaCibi", an.UsoCotturaCibi);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProduzioneAcquaCaldaSanitaria", an.ProduzioneAcquaCaldaSanitaria);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RiscaldamentoIndividuale", an.RiscaldamentoIndividuale);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsoCommerciale", an.UsoCommerciale);

                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader);

                    myReader.Close();
                    mycon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult("Modificato con successo");
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            return new JsonResult("Errore con la tua query: " + e);
        }
        
    }
```

Can someone help?

i was tring to do a put request using c# and i was expecting that it would have worked.
P.S the parameters that are going to be placed in the db are correct, i have already checked

Comment: `UPDADE contratti SET`  ???

Comment: UPDADE => UPDATE

Comment: and [can we stop using `AddWithValue` already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)